# Discord.py How to use the message that the bot WILL send?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
async def anyfunc(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, "Hi!")
    bot_message_id = ((bot's_last_message)).id
```

What to put in (()) to make the bot remember the id of the message that it will send?
Is there a way to take the id of the next (for example, user's) message (that hasn't been sent yet) as a variable?

Comment: I don't understand well, you want to get the bot's message ID?

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you added more information and made it clear as to what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.send()` returns the `discord.Message` instance of the message it sent, so you can store it in a variable.

```
message = await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, Hi!")
# do what you want with the message, in your case getting it's id
bot_message_id = message.id
```

As for your second question, if you want to get the response of a user to that message (so the next message a specific user will send), you can use the built-in `wait_for` for this.

```
def check(message):
    return message.author.id == the_id_of_that_user

message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
```

That way, the bot will literally `wait for` a message that makes your `check` function return `True`, or in this case a message sent by that very user. More info on that in the relevant [API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question very good but I'll try to answer. according to [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AsyncIterator.get) you can get someone's last message with using `channel.history().get()`. So here  is a example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
async def anyfunc(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, Hi!")
    bot_message_id = await ctx.channel.history().get(author__name="Bot's name").id
```

This will probably work but in case of error, maybe you can try `author__id=bot's id` instead of `author__name`.